# Why does controller method gets twice called? ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

This is my View Page:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("GetAction", "GetController", FormMethod.Post))
{
  //bodypage:
}
```

This is my controller method.

```
[ActionName("GetAction")]
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult GetAction(string i)
{
   //doing stuff:
    return View();
}
```

This is my Ajax call

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            $("#value").click(function () {
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: '@Url.Action("GetAction", "GetController")',
                    data:
                    {
                        'i': $("#i").val()
                    }
                });
            });
        });
```

I dont get it why controller getting called twice. I also even config my route class but i
dont know how to do it.

Comment: Where is value parameter?

Comment: This is my html elements

<input name="getaction" type="submit" id = "value"/>

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using ajax remove from the view button

```
type="submit
```

and fix the javascript:

```
  $("#value").click(function (e) {

 e.preventDefault();
 e.stopImmediatePropagation();

....your ajax code
});
```

Comment: thats great. thank you for your sharing your knowledge.

Comment: i think it doesnt works, sorry for my previous comment there. i already tried to remove the submit type and added the prevent default but it doesnt redirect to view.